# Overriding access restirction in quick search for Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

In Salesforce quick search option we want to allow users to search and open a record if they know exact details like Opportunity ID even though they don't have access to that specific record. Is this possible and if so how.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. Permissions are required and you cannot override that behavior.

Also, this might help:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Object-not-included-in-search-and-results-differ-for-users&language=en_US